# VFL with Size-Class-Specific Layout dynamic with orientation support

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes, visual-format-language

I have a navigation bar added programatically to the view with VFL (visual format language)

like this

```
navBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
self.view.addSubview(navBar)
let views = ["bar": navBar]
var constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[bar]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views:views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[bar(64)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views:views)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
```

the above code works fine but gives a constant height to the navigation bar as 64. **but I would like to have it based on the mobile's orientation, portrait-64 and landscape-44**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change height depending on orientation change you need to grab when **orientation change**

Below method will help you do this.So change your layout depending on orientation in this method too.

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
            print("Landscape")
            //Change your code here for landscape
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            //Change your code here for portrait
        }
    }
```

**Swift 3 version:**

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    }
```